# Skipping lines of text file

Tags: c#

So I had some assistance with this yesterday but now I needed to make a change and my change doesn't seem to work.  Wanted to see if someone would help me with what I'm doing wrong.

So here is an example of the file read in

[image: Example]

Now originally this was reading the FSD number of `0.264` then reading the first number in the first column of `3.4572` and the last number of that column.  This worked fine.  But now I know longer need that FSD number and I no longer need the first number `3.4572`.  Instead I need the first number that doesn't have `0.00` in the last column, and then the last number still.  So this is what I have but it isn't grabbing anything at all, `if (dataWithAvgVolts.Count() > 1)` is skipped.

```
public partial class FrmTravelTime : Form
{
    const string FSD__Line_Identifier = "Drilling Data";
    const string Data_Start_Point_Identifier = "AVG_VOLTS";
    const string Spark_Point_Identifier = "0.00";
    static readonly char[] splitter = { ' ', '\t' };

    public FrmTravelTime()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV_Hidden.Rows)
        {
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo();
            {
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(row.Cells["colfilelocation"].Value.ToString());
                var fsdLine = lines.FirstOrDefault(line => line.Contains(FSD__Line_Identifier));
                var dataWithAvgVolts = lines.SkipWhile(line => line.Contains(Data_Start_Point_Identifier + Spark_Point_Identifier + FSD__Line_Identifier)).ToList();

                if (dataWithAvgVolts.Count() > 1)
                {
                    var data = dataWithAvgVolts[1].Split(splitter);
                    info.startvalue = Convert.ToDouble(data[0]);
                    data = dataWithAvgVolts[dataWithAvgVolts.Count - 1].Split(splitter);
                    info.endvalue = Convert.ToDouble(data[0]);
                }

                info.finalnum = info.startvalue - info.endvalue;


            }
        }
    }

public class FileInfo
{
    public double startvalue;
    public double endvalue;
    public double firstnum;
    public double finalnum;
}
```

[image: Example 2]

So you see here the first line that finally does not have `0.00` is

`3.0164  7793   1   0   0.159   0.02`

So my `info.startvalue` will be `3.0164`

This goes down a good 100ish lines until the last line of 
`2.7182 8089    0   0   0.015   22.19`

So my `info.endvalue` should be `2.7182`

**@Amit**

```
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(row.Cells["colfilelocation"].Value.ToString());
                var fsdLine = lines.FirstOrDefault(line => line.Contains(FSD__Line_Identifier));
                info.FSD = fsdLine.Substring(fsdLine.IndexOf(FSD_Identifier) + FSD_Identifier.Length, 7);
                var dataWithAvgVolts = lines.SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains(Data_Start_Point_Identifier)).ToList();
                var data = lines.Where(line => (!line.Contains(Data_Start_Point_Identifier) && !line.Contains(FSD__Line_Identifier) && !line.EndsWith("0.00"))).ToList();

                if (data.Count > 1)
                {
                    var line = data[0];
                    var tempdata = data[0].Split(splitter);
                    info.startvalue = Convert.ToDouble(tempdata[0]);
                    var thisdata = data[data.Count - 1].Split(splitter);
                    info.endvalue = Convert.ToDouble(thisdata[0]);
                }
```

Comment: AVG_VOLTS is not contained in the same line where you find the 0.00

Comment: Based on the file days you shared, what should be the output?

Comment: The first line that does not contain `0.00` is `3.0164` which isn't shown, its much further down as there is a lot of `0.00`.  So I just need to grab the `3.0164` and then the last number, which on this particular file is much further down as `2.7182` as both `info.startvalue` and `info.endvalue`

Comment: Can you share one of your text files somewhere

Comment: Sure, nothing proprietary in this one https://expirebox.com/download/077a8d3c4e68eb2d110e07c3ee3396fc.html

Answer (score 1):

Your SkipWhile condition is incorrect.

```
  line => !line.Contains(Data_Start_Point_Identifier + Spark_Point_Identifier + FSD__Line_Identifier)
```

Will mean   `AVG_VOLTS0.00Drilling Data` . You are saying, skip the text file till the line does not contain AVG_VOLTS0.00Drilling Data. You do not have this is one line anywhere. So, basically, you seem to be skipping the entire file. Put up a else condition, that will work.

This line returns all rows which do not have "Drilling Data" word, "AVG_VOLTS" word, and do not end with "0.00".

```
var data = lines.Where(line=>(!line.Contains(Data_Start_Point_Identifier) && !line.Contains(FSD__Line_Identifier) && !line.EndsWith("0.00"))).ToList();
```

Then, take the rows, and process.

If condition can be

```
      if (data.Count > 1)
        {
            var line = data[0];
            var tempdata = data[0].Split(splitter);
            info.startvalue = Convert.ToDouble(tempdata[0]);
            var thisdata = data[data.Count - 1].Split(splitter);
            info.endvalue = Convert.ToDouble(thisdata[0]);
        }
```

Comment: This isnt a solution, just an indication of a problem. Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: So do I just need to tell it to skip if it does contain then?  I tried but `info.startvalue` errors as incorrect format.  But I do want to skip everything until the line does not have `0.00` take that first number then where its `0.02` in this case, which is `3.0164`

Comment: I've been playing around with it but can't get it to work with what I already have.  I'm sure its me, if it wasn't already obvious, this is my first time working with a file this way but I took it on so I could get the experience.

Comment: For example `var data = lines.All(line => !line.EndsWith("0.00")).ToList();` `.ToList()` doesn't work, errors as there is not option for `.ToList`

Comment: @Logan I have updated my answer with a line of code that is actually working for me.

Comment: @Amit ok your edit does give me a list that starts where I need it to start.  Then I get an error on `info.startvalue = Convert.ToDouble(data[0]);` that the data is not in the correct format. `Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: @Logan I have put the if condition to extract data, as per my understanding from your code in the question. You can change variables as per your choice.

Comment: @Amit that's pretty much exactly what I have.  But even a copy paste of yours still gives me `Input string was not in correct format` on `info.startvalue = Convert.ToDouble(tempdata[0]);`

Comment: @Logan: Check the name of your variables. This is actually working code for me. Hopefully, you are not using lines which have text in first column and casting it to double.

Comment: @Amit I added section up to to show what I have.  This gives me the error on `info.startvalue = Convert.ToDouble(tempdata[0]);` and no there are no characters in first column.

Comment: I think I fixed it.  I needed `data[1]` not `data[0]`

Comment: sure, might be your file structure is anyways slightly different from my sample file structure.